# How do I create an iOS7 style popup menu in Xcode?

Tags: cocoa-touch

Does anyone know how to create a popup menu like the one seen in the mail app on iOS7 which lets you reply, reply all, forward and print? I have been researching it but can't find an answer. I am still quite new to Xcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are after the UIActionSheet. This is a control found within all versions of iOS, but has recently been re-skined for iOS7.

**Update**: UIActionSheet was deprecated in iOS 8, and instead you should use UIAlertController with the style of `actionSheet`

Comment: The link in this answer is 404 - is this a suitable replacement? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/uikit_catalog_creating_and_customizing_views_and_controls

Comment: @halfer Updated the answer, UIActionSheet is no longer used